# Get user email addresses in mediawiki

Tags: php, mediawiki

How can I retrieve an array of email addresses from MediaWiki in php?

The reason is that I want to modify the [BlockAndNuke](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:BlockAndNuke) extension so that it shows the user's email address, and not just the username, at the special page `Special:BlockAndNuke`.

Comment: Could you edit your second paragraph to be more than one sentence?  I get lost halfway through.  Your grammar isn't helping the situation either (was->were, has->have, thus->this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method is called [`$user->getEmail();`](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/html/classUser.html#acf082b95b344df14b9e8a6c09868dbcd). Where you get the user object from, depends on how the extensions looks. If you intend to modify special page of the [BlockAndNuke](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:BlockAndNuke) extension, you would end up with something like

```
/* First create a user object for this user name */
$user = User::newFromName( $name );

/* Then ask for the users email address*/
$emailAddress = $user->getEmail();
```

You can also create a User object from an id: `$user = User::newFromId( $id )`